# Core Animation NSView LayerContentsRedrawPolicy

Tags: cocoa, core-animation, calayer, nsview, appkit

#### NB:

This question is about **layer-backed** NSViews on Mac OS 10.10. Please don't mention UIKit.

---

#### The Question

The Core Animation docs make it very clear that `NSViewLayerContentsRedrawOnSetNeedsDisplay` is the way to go for performant animations. My question is very simple: suppose I have a hierarchy of layer-backed NSViews like this:

```
WindowContentView
    ScrollView
        ClipView
            DocumentView
               SomeSubview
```

Each of these views is layer-backed, but none of them are set to draw their layer contents into their parent's layer.

Do I need to set the `redrawOnSetNeedsDisplay` policy on **every** view in the chain, or will setting that policy on the top-most view affect layers of child views? I can't find anything in the docs that discusses this.

The reason I ask is that while my animations are smooth-ish, there is still a bit of remaining choppiness and I can't figure out why.

Comment: What do you mean `set to draw their layer contents into their parent's layer.` What are the actual options you have set?

Comment: There's a property on NSView that tells that view it can draw its layer into the parent layer. Reduces compositing. I have not turned that on for any layers.

Comment: The windowcontentview has an explicit "wantsLayer" set (via IB). All other views have implicit layers. The redraw policy is set to "onNeedsDisplay" for windowContentView. I have not set the policy on any subviews thereof. So that's my question: are the subviews still using the default "redrawDuringViewResize" or do they inherit the "redrawOnSetNeedsDisplay" policy from their parent view?

Comment: Override `-drawInContext:` and figure it out. I'm not sure.